# Begin typing in a textfield after enabling editing with a button press?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a text field for storing the name of a user on their profile. I have an edit button to the right of the text field that enables editing so the user doesn't accidentally change their profile.

Here is my code:

```
struct ProfilePage: View { 
  @State private var name = "" 
  @State var nameEditEnabled = false 
  @AppStorage("NAME_KEY") var savedName = "" 

  var body: some View { 
    VStack { 
      HStack { 
        TextField("Name", text: $savedName) 
          .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder) 
          .font(.title) .disableAutocorrection(true) 
          .onChange(of: name) {text in 
             self.savedName = name } 
          .onSubmit { nameEditEnabled = false } 
          .disabled(nameEditEnabled ? false : true) 

          Button(action: {self.nameEditEnabled.toggle()}) {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil") 
          }
      }
    }
  .padding() 
  }
}
```

How would I go about making it so that when the button is pressed, the user automatically is put into the textfield and the keyboard pops up so that they can begin typing (without having to manually press the textfield)?

When I enable editing, it just enables the text field but doesn't have the user start typing in it (i.e. bring up the keyboard so that they can edit the text field).

EDIT: updated code for suggestions.

[GIF of what my app is doing](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/883925288101240842/1057936203078434888/Simulator_Screen_Recording_-_iPhone_14_Pro_-_2022-12-29_at_03.20.22.gif)

Comment: Look into `FocusState` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate

Answer (score 1):

You have to use focused for that see the below code:

```
@State private var name = ""
@State var nameEditEnabled = false

@FocusState var isFocusOn: Bool

VStack {
    HStack {
        TextField("Name", text: $name)
            .focused($isFocusOn)
            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
            .font(.title) .disableAutocorrection(true)
            .onSubmit { nameEditEnabled = false }

        Button(action: {
            isFocusOn = true
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
        }
    }
}
.padding()
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot. However, it only works after manually tapping the textfield once. Is there a way to make it work the first time?

Comment: @RocketBlaster05 You can set the `isFocusOn` property to true programatically, for instance `.onAppear { isFocusOn = true }`

Comment: Hmm... I added that but it still has the same output. I have to manually touch the textfield in order to get the system to work.